# How to create parallel diagonals in a table cell?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, graphics, tikz-matrix

How to create the following pattern of parallel diagonals in the table?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [**diagbox package**](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/diagbox/diagbox.pdf) which can be used for drawing diagonal lines in cells. Unfortunately, this package doesn't support parallel diagonals out of the box. So, here comes `tikz` to the rescue. The trick in the solution below is to determine the cell height and width in advance. The width is specified as `12em` by the code `@{}p{12em}@{}` and the height is specified as `6em` by appending an empty column of zero width and adding `\parbox{0cm}{\rule{0pt}{6em}}` in the second row.

The center of the cell with diagonals is then calculated using `tikzmark` and `calc` tikz libraries. Finally the diagonals are drawn using tikz on top of the table using the options `[overlay,remember picture]`. The solution is not exact and requires some manual calculations but suffices such cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{document}    

$D_N = $
\begin{tabular}{|c|@{}p{12em}@{}|c|@{}c@{}}
   \hline
   $\frac{2N^2+1}{6}$ &  &  & \\
   \hline
   & \parbox{12em}{% 
   \hfill$\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{x_i-x_j}$ \ \par
   \hfill\tikzmark{1}$\frac{-x_j}{2(1-x_j^2)}$\tikzmark{2}\hfill\null\par
   \ $\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{x_i-x_j}$
   } &  &\parbox{0cm}{\rule{0pt}{6em}} \\
   \hline
   &  &  $-\frac{2N^2+1}{6}$ & \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \coordinate(o) at ([yshift=.26ex] $(pic cs:1)!.5!(pic cs:2)$); 
    \draw ([shift={(-3em,3em)}]o)--([shift={(6em,-1.5em)}]o);
    \draw ([shift={(-6em,1.5em)}]o)--([shift={(3em,-3em)}]o);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]